# rbinding two ffdf data frames in R

Tags: r

Another question about the `ff` package. Is there a `rbind` equivalent function in the `ff` or `ffbase` package in R? I want to bind two `ff` data frames by rows. Can this be done in the `ff` package or are there other libraries that could help me?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `ff` package but I see in the [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ff/ff.pdf) a function called `crbind`. Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: I tried the ffdfappend function but got an error. I tried it also on a toy example:

fd<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=T)
fd<-data.frame(fd)
colnames(fd)<-c("col1","col2")
fd<-as.ffdf(fd)
fd

fd1<-matrix(c(5,6,7,8),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=T)
fd1<-data.frame(fd1)
colnames(fd1)<-c("col1","col2")
fd1<-as.ffdf(fd1)
fd1
?ffdfappend
vd<-ffdfappend(fd,fd1)

I got the following error:
Error in UseMethod("as.ffdf") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.ffdf' applied to an object of class "ffdf"

Comment: if I do vd<-ffdfappend(fd,data.frame(fd1)) it works so will test out large example to see if it is heavy on RAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there are no new factor levels in fd1, you can set `adjustvmode` to `FALSE` as below.

```
vd<-ffdfappend(fd, fd1, adjustvmode=F)
```

Answer (score 2):

use ffdfappend from version 0.6 of the ffbase package.
The ffdfappend of version 0.5 was designed to append a data.frame to an ffdf, while the one from version 0.6 also allows appending an ffdf to an ffdf.
You can install version 0.6 of that package by using the following R code:

```
download.file(url="http://fffunctions.googlecode.com/git-history/b6fa5617810e012e5d809d77a9a99dbb25c7e6dc/output/ffbase_0.6.tar.gz", destfile="ffbase_0.6.tar.gz")
install.packages("ffbase_0.6.tar.gz", repos=NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

`rbind()` works with `ffdf` objects as desired. For example:

```
df1 = as.ffdf(data.frame(A = 21:23, B = letters[1:3]))
df2 = as.ffdf(data.frame(A = 31:34, B = letters[11:14]))
df3 = as.ffdf(data.frame(A = 41:42, B = letters[21:22]))
rbind(df1, df2, df3)
```

Yields:

```
ffdf (all open) dim=c(9,2), dimorder=c(1,2) row.names=NULL
ffdf virtual mapping
PhysicalName VirtualVmode PhysicalVmode  AsIs VirtualIsMatrix PhysicalIsMatrix PhysicalElementNo PhysicalFirstCol PhysicalLastCol PhysicalIsOpen
A            A      integer       integer FALSE           FALSE            FALSE                 1                1               1           TRUE
B            B      integer       integer FALSE           FALSE            FALSE                 2                1               1           TRUE
ffdf data
   A  B
1 21 a 
2 22 b 
3 23 c 
4 31 k 
5 32 l 
6 33 m 
7 34 n 
8 41 u 
9 42 v
```